# Can't copy .bat file into .exe file

Tags: batch-file, installation, exe, nsis

I'm trying to create .exe file with include a batch file (configure.bat) in a sub folder ($_OUTDIR) again to execute it after run .exe file.
But batch file doesn't come.

```
!ifdef INNER
....
  OutFile "${OUTPUT_DIR}\${SHORT_NAME}-${VERSION}-${RELEASE}.exe"
....
!endif

....
....
....

Section "Install" Install
....
    SetOutPath "$_OUTDIR"
    File ${TLM_DIR}\*
    ExecWait '"$_OUTDIR\configure.bat"'
....
SectionEnd
```

Could you help me to done this?

Comment: Why are you using $_OUTDIR? Please don't use undocumented internal variables...

Comment: Because in execute file (Project_name.exe) are including..

  - Folder $COMMONFILES
  - Folder $PLUGSINTDIR
  - Folder $TEMP
  - Folder $_OUTDIR
  - Folder doc
  - Other files

and I need to copy configure.bat to $_OUTDIR path.

Comment: Are you talking about decompiling installers? I know you will find $_OutDir if you do that but like I said, it is undocumented and should not be used. Even if it wasn't, the way you are using it with SetOutPath is wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_OUTDIR` is a internal undocumented NSIS variable! The variable set by SetOutPath is `$OUTDIR` but the input should be something else.

```
Section
InitPluginsDir
SetOutPath $PluginsDir
File MyStuff\*
ExecWait '"$OutDir\config.bat"'
SetOutPath $Temp ; Don't lock the plugin folder so it can be deleted
SectionEnd
```

You normally don't use `$OutDir` anywhere, just use $InstDir...